# Error: The target entry-point "angular-in-memory-web-api" has missing dependencies:

Tags: angular, http, webapi

throw new Error(`The target entry-point "${invalidTarget.entryPoint.name}" has missing dependencies:
^

Error: The target entry-point "angular-in-memory-web-api" has missing dependencies:

- rxjs/Observable
- rxjs/BehaviorSubject
- rxjs/observable/of
- rxjs/observable/fromPromise
- rxjs/util/isPromise
- rxjs/operator/concatMap
- rxjs/operator/first
- rxjs/operator/map

Comment: Hi, it's an RxJs proble? Try an "npm i rxjs".